# When does lookup for a name happen and when does it not?

Tags: python, python-3.x

From Python in a Nutshell

> ```
> class B(object):
>   def f(self): return 23
>   g = property(f)
> class C(B):
>   def f(self): return 42
> c = C()
> print(c.g)                # prints: 23, not 42
> ```
>
> ... **the property performs no lookup for that name**, but rather uses
>   the function object it was passed at creation time.
>
> If you need to work around this issue, you can always do it by adding
>   the extra level of lookup indirection yourself:
>
> ```
> class B(object):
>   def f(self): return 23
>   def _f_getter(self): return self.f()
>   g = property(_f_getter)
> class C(B):
>   def f(self): return 42
> c = C()
> print(c.g)                # prints: 42, as expected
> ```
>
> Here, the function object held by the property is  B._f_getter , which
>   in turn **does perform a lookup for name  f  (since it calls  self.f()
>   )**;

What does "lookup" mean here?

In what conditions does "lookup" happen?

What is the rule governing that a property doesn't perform lookup while `self.f()` does?

Thanks.

Comment: What is "a proper"?  Do you mean a property?

Answer (score 4):

"Lookup" means basically "taking a name and getting the value it points to".  In general, name lookup happens when the line containing a name is executed.

In your first example, the line containing `property(f)` is only executed once, when `B` is defined.  So the name `f` is only looked up at that time.  `f` is still *called* every time you access `obj.g`, but in this case `f` doesn't look up any names (it just returns a constant).

In your second example, the line containing `property(_f_getter)` is still only executed once, so `_f_getter` is still only looked up once.  But `_f_getter` is *called* every time you access `obj.g`, so the line inside `_f_getter` is executed on every such attribute access.  That means that every attribute access will execute the code in `_f_getter`, and will look up the value of `self` (and then `self.f`).

There is no rule that says "a property doesn't perform lookup".  The thing is that a property is only created once, so any lookup that happens during the *creation* of the property will only happen once.  But the property causes a function to be called on every access, so any lookup that happens inside that function will take place on every access.